# Unpacking a bitfield in php?

Tags: php

Is this even possible? basically I have a c++ application which sends packed 32 bit integers to a web server. the php file queries the web server and retrieves a xml file containing all of this packed data, now knowing the format of this packed data isnt a problem, its just how can I make this usable?

the data is made up of different types. some will be single bits, others will be 8 or 16 depending on what it is im storing

any info on this would be greatly appreceated. thanks!

Comment: Have you seen PHP's [`unpack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) function?

Comment: how does single bit look like in xml? is it string 1 or 0?

Comment: Will have a look at that unpack function. cheers

Comment: its a 32 bit integer. so a single set bit would be 1. 2 set bits would be 3. 3 set bits would be 7 etc! basically just the integer representation of a binary bit field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP supports bitwise operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

So after you have an integer variable with the packed data in PHP, just bitwise-and it with a bitmask, and you get the field you want. Like this:

```
$myInteger = 5;                              // bit representation 101
$leastMeaningfulBit = $myInteger & (1 << 0); // sets $leastMeaningfulBit to 1.
$secondBit = $myInteger & (1 << 1);          // sets $secondBit to 0.
$thirdBit = $myInteger & (1 << 2);           // sets $thirdBit to 1.
```

etc.